# Java UDP datagram packet - slicing data to suit buffer size

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, udp, client-server

in Java, UDP datagram packets uses a fixed size of byte array to send and receive streams through the network.

1. if the data I want to send is bigger than the buffer how to slice the data to suit the datagram packet ?
2. if data is sliced at the client side to suitable datagrams, how to know the number of packets I should receive ?
3. if I used `String.getBytes()` at the client side to send all data in one buffer, then at the server how know the exact length of packet or data I need to receive as all data I should receive ?

plus: I know that UDP packet should not be too long (i.e. not exceeding 548 byte), that means slicing the data at client is more efficient.

Comment: The short answer to all of these questions is, "however you want". You have a datagram service and if you want to send information over it, you need to work out some way to map that information to datagrams.

Comment: I did reach a simple solution but don't know how exactly to implement it. 
the code I'm trying to use is:

`while(exp){
                DatagramPacket pRcv = new DatagramPacket(
                    new byte[1024], 1024);
                s.receive(pRcv);
}`

then what specific `exp` should I use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

1. Choose a maximum datagram size *N* you will send - 548 for example.  You could try larger values up to 65535.
2. Split the data into chunks of size *N - 6*.
3. In each chunk, use 2 bytes for the datagram number and 2 bytes for the datagram length.  Use the 2 remaining bytes to send the total number of datagrams.  Yes this "wastes" 2 bytes in most datagrams but it makes the code simpler.

When each datagram is received, use the first 6 bytes to reassemble the datagrams into the complete data.

Comment: I did reach a simple solution but don't know how exactly to implement it. the code I'm trying to use is: `while(exp){ DatagramPacket pRcv = new DatagramPacket( new byte[1024], 1024); s.receive(pRcv); }`.. then what specific `exp` should I use ?

Comment: @PoulaAdel It depends what the simple solution that you reached is, which you haven't told us.